# No puedo subir un proyecto a pypi

Tags: python, anaconda

Estoy intentando subir un proyecto a pypi con este comando: `setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest` pero obtengo este error:

```
File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
setup(name='spongebot', version='1.0', packages=find_packages(), description = 'Upload a gif of Spongebob')
File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\upload.py", line 63, in run
self.upload_file(command, pyversion, filename)
File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\upload.py", line 73, in upload_file
raise AssertionError("unsupported schema " + schema)
AssertionError: unsupported schema
```

Puede ser del `setup.py`:
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages

```
setup(
    name='spongebot', 
    version='1.0', 
    packages=find_packages(), 
    description = 'Upload a gif of Spongebob',
)
```

O del `.pypirc`:

```
[distutils]
index-servers=
    pypi
    test

[pypitest]
repository = https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
username = my_username

[pypi]
# repository = https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username = my_username
```

Comment: Creo que los servidores listados bajo `[distutils]` deben coincidir con las secciones que luego tienes. Por tanto la línea `test` debería decir `pypitest`. Además de eso asegúrate de tener la última versión de `setuptools`.

Comment: He hecho ambas cosas y sigue sin funcionar.